# How hide and display amp script from SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, content-builder

I'm trying to hide %%=v(@left_title)=%% ampscript from the content display and when click on the preview it should be load the data for that particular variable. And also does anyone know how to identify the exact code block if the email is too long(when we start developing an email using code block it's bit hard to identify the exact location when needs to some changes)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot and should not try to hide this.
This is in-line AMPscript, used directly for displaying content in the email body, it’s not possible to hide it without deleting it.

It is only possible to hide AMPscript blocks (not in-line AMPscript) using HTML comment tags:

```
<!== ampscript block ==>
```

But this is also not advised:

> Do not try to hide your AMPscript code with HTML comments or blocks.
> This often leads to inadvertent code inclusion, especially in the
> text-only version of your email.

Source: https://ampscript.guide/best-practices-script-block-organization/

As to identifying code blocks, it’s best to use AMpscript comments to mark what each peace of scipt does: https://ampscript.guide/comments/

Here's a screenshot of what I mean by using comments for marking what each block does:

[image]

Comment: I have to use many code blocks for same email. without clicking on the code block is there any way to identify that code block?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "identifying", but I've updated my answer to show you what I meant. If this answer helped you, please remember to mark it as accepted by ticking the checkmark - thanks!

Comment: I also utilize the `%%[ /*Code Block Title <div style="display:none;">*/ ....your code here... /*</div>*/ ]%%` method to help hide display without any major effect to the code. You will want to keep this in mind though as there have been some edge cases with unexpected behavior.

Comment: I'm not in favor of masking complexity for the sake of "making it look good in Content Builder".  If you must, just use the long form of the AMPscript block tags: `<script runat='server' language='ampscript'> /* your AMPscript here */</script>`